# Confidence in Zero Defects

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, confidence-interval

A friend of mine sent me a stats question, and since stats is definitely one of my weak points, I struggled a bit with this one, and I'm looking for some help.

The question is

> Imagine a production line with $N$ units. Each unit has probability $p$ of being defective, but we don't know $p$.
>   How many units do we have to inspect in order to be 95% confident that there are no defects in the batch?

I can't claim to have a good understanding of what a confidence interval means, but here's my attempt. If we've observed some data $X = x_0$, and we want to estimate the underlying parameter $p$ with confidence $1-\alpha$, then we're looking for the interval in which our observation isn't "unusual"; i.e., $P(X=x_0;p) > \alpha$.

So, since our observation is "we saw no defects in our sample", and we're trying to estimate the number of defects total (which isn't a parameter!), I think a sensible interpretation is:

> A number of defects $d$ is in our confidence interval iff $P(\textrm{no defects in sample} | d \textrm{ defects in batch}) > \alpha$

In our case, we want our sample to be large enough that our confidence interval is just $0$. So I think the question I want to answer is:

> For what sample size does $P(\textrm{no defects in sample} | \textrm{some failures in the batch}) \le \alpha?$

---

So here's my approach to that problem, whether or not it's the correct problem.

If $S$ is the event that we have no defects in the sample, and $F$ is the event there are no defects in the batch. Also let $q = 1-p$, and $m$ be our sample size.
\begin{align*}
P(S | F) &= \frac{P(S) P(F | S)}{P(F)} \\
&= \frac{q^m (1 - q^{N-m})}{1 - q^N} \\
&= \frac{q^m - q^N}{1 - q^N}
\end{align*}

So we're looking for $m$ such that $\frac{q^m - q^N}{1 - q^N} \le 0.05$. But we don't know $q$. From [a common result](http://asq.org/quality-progress/2007/11/basic-quality/zero-defect-sampling.html), our confidence interval on $p$, given we haven't seen any defects in the sample, is approximately $[0, 3/m]$. Worst case scenario it's $3/m$, so we'll use that:
$$ \frac{(1-3/m)^m - (1-3/m)^N}{1 - (1-3/m)^N} \le 0.05$$

From there it's numerical.

---

Was this at all the right approach? If not, what's a more correct one?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the alternative to no defect is that there is one defect in a batch of $N$:

Then if you sample $m$ *without replacement*, the probability of not spotting that defect is $1-\frac{m}{N}$. So to have a probability of $0.05$ or less of failing to find that defect you need $m \ge 0.95 N$, so rounding up

If sampling *with replacement*, then the sample size $m$ would have to satisfy $\left(1-\frac1N\right)^m \le 0.05$ i.e. $m \ge \frac{\log(0.05)}{\log\left(1-\frac1N\right)}$, which can be approximated using $e^{-m/N}\lesssim 0.05$ requiring $m \gtrsim -N \log_e(0.05) \approx 3N$ corresponding to the rule you seem to have found (empirically, $3N-1$ turns out to be big enough)